# How to make gatedate() work for different time zones in ms sql server

Tags: sql-server, timezone

Ok I've one table in my db with column "Order_Placed_Date". The default value of this column is set to **getdate()** and as my db is configured for **India Standard Time (IST GMT+05:30)**, the value inserted in the column will be current time in India.

Now I've another table "Time_Zone" with column "Time_Zone_Code" which holds the user's time zone code.

What I want is that in "Order_Placed_Date" column instead of inserting the current time for IST, gatedate() should insert current time for the Time Zone Code stored in "Time_Zone" table.

Suppose column "Time_Zone_Code" has value **Eastern Standard Time** then in Order_Placed_Date column the time inserted should be current time for EST and not IST.

There is one function in sql server 2008 [SWITCHOFFSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677244.aspx) which returns the offset between two time zones but little confused, how to use it in my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server does not have this functionality.  Consider performing time zone adjustments in your application code instead.

For example, if you are using .NET in your application code, then you can use the `TimeZoneInfo` class.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Matt I am doing the date calculation in my c# code and then inserting the calculated value in the Order_Placed_Date column. I wrote following function

```
public string getDateForProvideTimeZone(string TimeZoneId)
{
            TimeZoneInfo _timeZoneInfo;
            DateTime _dateTime;

            _timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZoneId);
            _dateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, _timeZoneInfo);
            return _dateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
}
```